# How can I set Output cache in Downstream?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I manage a separate memory to store my Cache contents (asp.net output cache directive)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but downstream caches are controlled by the `Cache-Control` header, the standard way to use downstream caches is to specify `public`, i.e. `Cache-Control:public`  if your `Cache-Control` header is set to `private`, it will only be cached by the browser.  it's also recommended you set a max age like this: `Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000` (that will cache a static resource for a month).

Also note that most down-stream caches will NOT cache any url with a `?` character, so it's recommended that you encode any parameters you need into the file-name or path.

More info on the google developer blog:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching